# SyntaxError: Named export 'express' not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, phpmyadmin

I have a CRUD project based on react and nodejs. when I try to index.js, I recieve the following error: [Named export 'express' not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWe3W.png) ( please open the image to see the error)

The index.js code is the following

```
import express  from "express" ;
import cors from "cors" ;
import UserRoute from "./routes/UserRoute.js" ;
//import Types from 'mongoose'
const app =express(); 
app.use(cors()); 
app.use(express.json());
app.use(UserRoute); 
app.listen(5000,()=>console.log('server up and running...')) ;
```

The UserRoute.js file code is the following :

```
import { express } from "express";
import { getUsers }from "../controllers/UserController.js"
const router =express.router(); 
router.get('/users',getUsers); 
export default router
```

I hope you may help me to find the solution.

Comment: For your space-related issue please check import express. 
import express from 'express';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import express from "express";
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please use it?

const express = require("express");

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).